# Lego Digital Designer on OS X El Capitan?

Tags: ldd, cad, mac

Since the El Capitan 10.11.2 upgrade some options are gone in Lego Digital Designer. In the Preferences menu the "Outlines of bricks" and "Advanced shading" are options unselectable.

The annoying part is that without brick outlines it is hard to use for building new things since it is impossible to see where the bricks start.

I have looked at this forum:
http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=115313

There is a quoted workaround that suggests deleting these lines from the Info.plist file of the app:
LSMinimumSystemVersion
10.4.11

But it does not work for me.

Any other workaround appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

LEGO Software in general doesn't work that great with Apple computers (I a speaking from experience). Try a couple of different solutions by searching the web, and contact LEGO Support. Hope you find a solution!

Comment: The idea is to  accumulate answers here.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [WINE](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX) to run LDD for Windows.